# IDEA maven dependency package cannot be downloaded

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I used unused images to download the files, and having below errors. In general, there were both.

1. Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-context:pom:5.1.7.RELEASE from/to nexus-aliyun (http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required

Comment: verify your proxies, and also see if valid https certificate is installed.

Comment: Where do you see this issue? Does it work from command line Maven?

Comment: First the url you have given above looks strange to me...Central repository has a different url and most important uses https instead of http...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proxy in your **pom.xml** as shown in below example

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your nexus proxies mavencentral trough http, but mavencentral  [dropped http support](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https) 
I guess your nexus is not configured properly now [proxy to Maven Central repo](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts)

[image]